# MYSQL How to order items mixed according to the shop id

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table like this.

```
+----+-----------+---------+
| id | product   | shop_id |
+----+-----------+---------+
|  1 | Product 1 |       1 |
|  2 | Product 2 |       3 |
|  3 | Product 3 |       2 |
|  4 | Product 4 |       3 |
|  5 | Product 5 |       1 |
|  6 | Product 6 |       2 |
+----+-----------+---------+
```

I want to order it by shop id. Order should be like this

```
Product 1 => Shop_id 1
Product 3 => Shop_id 2
Product 2 => Shop_id 3
Product 5 => Shop_id 1
Product 6 => Shop_id 2
Product 4 => Shop_id 3
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: in sql, not very easily. you've got a randomish ordering of the products. `order by` with random-ish ordering rules never works out well.

Comment: That's not *order by shop id*. Otherwise, your order of `(product, shop_id)` would be `(Product 1, 1)`, `(Product 5, 1)`, `(Product 3, 2)`, `(Product 6, 2)`, `(Product 2, 3)`, `(Product 4, 3)`. What is the rule for ordering that you want? It looks like you want to *cycle* through `shop_id` and, each time, choose the `shop_id` with the lowest `product` number, which is more complex. But it's not necessarily clear from your small example.

Comment: taking items randomly is not solution for me Marc B. I think question is clear. I just want to take items in a queue according to shop_id. Yes I want cycle through shop_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT x.*  
 FROM my_table x 
 JOIN my_table y 
   ON y.shop_id = x.shop_id 
  AND y.id <= x.id 
GROUP BY x.id 
ORDER 
   BY COUNT(*)
    , shop_id;
```

... or, for larger data sets...

```
SELECT a.id
     , a.product
     , a.shop_id
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , IF(shop_id = @prev,@i:=@i+1,@i:=1) i
            , @prev := shop_id 
         FROM my_table x
            , (SELECT @i:=1,@prev:='') vars 
        ORDER   
           BY shop_id
            , id
     ) a
 ORDER 
    BY i,shop_id;
```

Comment: very complex. I think it also will have performance issues if i have  big data. But thank you. at least I learned there is no function to do it easily in mysql.

Comment: Complex? Hardly. But it's not optimal in terms of performance. Variables would work better on larger datasets.

Comment: do you have any suggestion for large datasets ? or is this solution good for larger datasets ?